# Error in progress/kendo-angular-l10n in Node Modules with Angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular6

I have just updated the `@progress/kendo-angular-l10n` in my project for Angular 6. When i am running `ng-build` it is throwing me the following error:

```
node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular- 
 l10n/dist/es2015/localization.service.d.ts(3,10): 
 error TS2305: Module '"C:/Samples/Project1/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' 
 has no exported member 'Subject'.

node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular- 
l10n/dist/es2015/message.service.d.ts(1,10): 
error TS2305: Module '"C:/Samples/Project1/Web/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"'
has no exported member 'Subject'.
```

I have installed the following packages also:

1. @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns
2. @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs

The above error is coming in these also.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772574/error-in-kendo-ui-controls-with-angular-6/52772749?noredirect=1#comment92467440_52772749)

Insalling the rxjs-compat solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

did you install rxjs `npm install rxjs`, or wich version do you have ?
dit you install the last v 1.2.1 for @progress/kendo-angular-l10n ?
rebuild the project, or delete the node_modules and reinstall dependecies.

Comment: i have the following versions:

"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^3.4.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^3.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.2.1",

Comment: I have deleted node_modules and execute npm install but still facing the issue

Comment: In you package.json do you install the rxjs ? or try downgrade with  1.2.0
 version for @progress/kendo-angular-l10n. After that, delete package-lock.json or  yarn.lock and the node_modules. And if it not working Please, update to the latest version using npm update, again.